# Good way to check if an ideal is principal in cubic extensions

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-number-theory, ideal-class-group

I've recently been tacking the computation of class groups. I've noticed that when dealing with a ramified prime ideal in a quadratic field $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{d}), d \in \mathbb{Z}$ squarefree, it's very easy to check to see if an ideal is principle, due to being able to make norm arguments $N(a+b\sqrt{d}) = a^2 - db^2$. However, in cubic fields this intuition breaks down since I don't have a norm; I was wondering if you could recommend a good plan of attack in these extensions.

Take for example: Let $K = \mathbb{Q}(\eta), \eta^3 = 6$. We know that $Disc(K) = -27*6^2 = 972$, which implies that Minkowski's bound is about $M_k = 8.82$. Now we examine primes

- Suppose $p = 2$

Then notice that $x^3 - 6 \equiv_2 x^3 \implies 2\mathcal{O}_K = (2, \eta)^3 = \mathfrak{p}_2^3$.

- Suppose $p = 3$.

Then again we have $3 \mathcal{O}_K = (3, \eta)^3 = \mathfrak{p}_3^3$.

- Suppose $p = 5$.

Then we have $x^3 - 6 \equiv x^3 + 4 \equiv (x-1)(x^2+x+1)$. This implies that $5\mathcal{O}_K = (5, \eta - 1)(5, \eta^2 + \eta + 1) = \mathfrak{p}_5\mathfrak{q}_5$.

- Suppose $p = 7$.

Then we have $x^3 - 6 \equiv x^3 + 1 \equiv (x-3)(x-5)(x-6)$. Therefore we can write $7 \mathcal{O}_K = (7, \eta - 3)(7, \eta - 5)(7, \eta - 6) = \mathfrak{p}_7 \mathfrak{q}_7 \mathfrak{q}_7'$.

Now that i've done this I want to show each of those individual prime ideals are principle, since I know that this field actually has class number 1.

For example, I'm confused on how to see that $(2, \eta) = (\eta - 2)$. I mean it's easy to see once I know to try $\eta - 2$, but how could I come up with that value besides guess and check. Even more so with $(3, \eta) = (-\eta^2 - 2\eta - 3)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the answer.

The problem was that I was too hasty in declaring that in cubic extensions, the ring of integers does not have a norm. In fact, I noticed that the norm in quadratic extensions was actually the field norm of the element $a + b\sqrt{d}$.

$$
N_{\mathcal{O}_K/\mathbb{Z}}(a+b\sqrt{d}) = \det \begin{pmatrix}
a & bd \\
b & a
\end{pmatrix} = a^2 - db^2
$$

So then when we consider this cubic extension, and repeat this process (let $\eta$ be such that $\eta^3 = 6$.)

$$
N_{\mathcal{O}_K/\mathbb{Z}}(a+b\eta + c\eta^2) = \det \begin{pmatrix}
a & 6c & 6b \\
b & a & 6c \\
c & b & a
\end{pmatrix} = a^3 + 6b^3 + 36c^3 - 18abc
$$

Then using this we can perform norm arguments like in the quadratic scenario. For example, notice that we can construct an element with norm $2$ by choose $a = 2, b = -1 \implies 2 - \eta$ is a element of norm $2$, which answers my question.